# Using fetch() with API

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I try to use `fetch()` to get the data from https://swapi.co/
With this code I get undefined but in the "Network" section in chrome I see the data I need. How I can access it?

```
fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/1/')
.then(resp => resp.json)
.then(obj => console.log(obj));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello this will fetch the data returning it as json

```js
fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/1')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have right environment for calling to the fetch API there maybe 2 result

1. You will get the right result data
2. You will get an error

   ```
   fetch(url) // Call the fetch function passing the url of the API as a parameter
   .then(function() {
                   // Your code for handling the data you get from the API
   })
   .catch (function() {
                   // This is where you run code if the server returns any errors
   });
   ```

Use a catch for seen what is going wrong with your request

Comment: I got: ƒ json() { [native code] } in the "console" section in chrome which means that I got a result but I don't understand how to access the data I see in the "Network" section in chrome.

Comment: Ok i understand you. It is ok in chrome but you have an error on your client side. The catch will say you what is reason. Debug it on catch. For example it may need an extra toJson but you have to be sure by seen the exception

Comment: My friend thanks for the help. My mistake was that I forgot use () in resp.json().

Comment: That is extra toJson :)